# Weird CSS visual bug showing only on Android mobile phones

Tags: android, css

As you'll see, the header of this site loads fine in all web browsers and iOS devices. Only on Android (Droid phone) is the header not showing up and instead just displays a text link. Help please? :) Screenshot of bug vs. how it's supposed to look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ixrbsrj8rgln0a/Screenshot%202014-01-08%2022.34.00.png

Link to site: http://ubd.me/bmb

UPDATE: I just tested it on an Android emulator and the header (logo, menu and search) load on initial load but are then replaced by just the text link... So confused.

UPDATE. Fixed it. I needed to use a more specific meta viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=100%; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1; user-scalable=no;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be because the image is being used as a background image. Try use the image with the normal image markup.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The header is CSS, not an image. Only the background is an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :-

```
<a href="http://ubd.me/bmb/"><img src='your_img.jpg'></a>
```

Comment: If this shows the img on ANdriod mobiles, you need to change your CSS further.

Comment: It's not just the image, it's the header including the menu dropdown and search box. Literally nothing is showing up on Android except the text link.